# Not able to delete calendar event in iPhone

Tags: calendar, iphone

I'm facing this issue that i have accepted a friend's invitation for call and it got added as a calendar event in my iPhone. Now the issue is when i'm opening it, there i'm unable to find the edit button from which i can delete this event from the calendar.

Has anyone faced similar issue like this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I removed the mail account from the device and then added it again. By doing this i was able to remove those events from iPhone calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem before, so I have a work round that might help:

- Create a new calendar on your iPhone. Let's call it 'Unwanted'
- Go to your unwanted iPhone event, open it, then move it to 'Unwanted'
- After you have moved your unwanted event to 'Unwanted', simply delete the 'Unwanted' calendar from your iPhone.

It helped me to remove the event that had no edit button.

Comment: How to move the event to the newly created event?